# Javascript Lookup Array, Return Corresponding Value

Tags: javascript

I have a script that fetches a part of a webpage. A small portion of it fetches the Team Name:

```
var teamName = tblRow.find ("td:eq(1)").text().trim().split(" vs")[0]
```

This will return something like `Chicago Bears` or `San Francisco 49ers`.

Is there a way for me to create an array like

```
Chicago Bears    CHI
San Francisco 49ers    SF
...
```

that will replace a team name with the abbrevated team name?

I know I can use `$.inArray(value, array)` to see if a value is in an array but I just want to return the corresponding column value. Error checking does not need to be performed to see if value exists in array.

Comment: Why is question entitled "Modify Multiple Strings"? Also, why would you use `$.inArray` when you could just use `array.indexOf`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a lookup object:

```
var teamNames = {
    "Chicago Bears": "CHI",
    ...
}
```

And then do:

```
var teamName = tblRow.find ("td:eq(1)").text().trim().split(" vs")[0]
var abbv = teamNames[teamName];
```